# Set associative cache

Tags: memory

A computer system uses 32 bit memory address and it has a main memory consisting 1Gb. It has a 4kb cache organised in block set associative manner with 4blocks per set and 64bytes per block. Calculate the number of bits in each tag,set,word fields of the memory address

Answer (score 0):

This simulator can help you: [www.cachesimulator.com](http://www.cachesimulator.com)

[image]

After the simulated cache have loaded you can find the address layout under "Cache information". 
[image]